# Trigger a Click on only First load and mobile screen width

Tags: javascript

My CSS Element triggering a click but not with specific width and on mobile i have came across such thing but no success

```
<script>
$( document ).on( 'ready', function() {

var handleMatchMedia = function (mediaQuery) {
  if (mediaQuery.matches) {

    $('.toggle-content-item').click();

} 
},

mql = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)');

handleMatchMedia(mql); 
mql.addListener(handleMatchMedia); 

} );
</script>
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you sure your browser window is within the media query being sent? At full width, the `mediaQuery.matches` shows `false` but if I make it super small, it returns `true` as expected.

Comment: Yes its working but sometimes it not. so i want it everytime to trigger whenever the site loads,refreshed on mobile device